# How to avoid InDesign adding pages automatically?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I don't know why it's doing this but it keeps adding pages horizontally, when I delete those 2 on the right, it adds them again automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's because you create the document with a **Primary Text Frame**. InDesign automatically add pages at the end of the document while the text flows. I don't see well your image but maybe there are some invisible characters flowing. Personally I recommend checking **Primary Text Frame** in new documents only for novels or books with fluent text.

[image: Primary Text Frame]

To avoid this, go to **Preferences** → **Type** → uncheck **Smart Text Reflow**

[image: Smart Text Reflow]

Comment: Thank God! You are the man! This was seriously bugging me haha, fixed the issue.

Thanks!